# How do I update the records from the SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I have users table. the user has a username and nickname. The username can be null. How do I write a single MySQL query that updates the user's username by a nickname when the user has no username?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You don't need to update the table. You can just use COALESCE inside a SELECT

Comment: For next time, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET username = nickname
WHERE username IS NULL
```

WHERE prevents updating for a row which has `username` value set to something, so only rows without the value in this column are updated.

Comment: it worked like a charm! you saved my day. Thank you so much sir.